# xslt how to add special attributes to copy-of

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML Code:

```
<root>
 <Kursstamm>
     <Texteinmischdefinitionen>
         <Texteinmischung Typ="Text" Position="Vorlauftext">Text A</Texteinmischung>
     </Texteinmischdefinitionen>
     <KursstammID>Text B
 </KursstammID>
 <Kursstammtitel>Text C</Kursstammtitel>
 <Kurztext>Text D</Kurztext>
 <Kursgebühr>Price</Kursgebühr>
 <Trainerprosa>Text E</Trainerprosa>
   <Texteinmischdefinitionen>
     <Texteinmischung Typ="Text" Position="Hinweistext">Text F </Texteinmischung>
   </Texteinmischdefinitionen>
 </Kursstamm>
</root>
```

And I like to process it with XSLT to:

```
Text A
Text B
Text C
Text D
Text E
Text F
```

I have problems with Text A and Text F!

I use this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/root/Kursstamm">
<xsl:copy-of select="Texteinmischung[@Typ='Vorlauftext']" />
<xsl:copy-of select="KursstammID"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="Kurztext"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="Kursgebühr"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="Trainerprosa"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="Nachlauf"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="Texteinmischung[@Typ='Hinweistext']" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it did not find

```
<Texteinmischung Typ="Text" Position="Vorlauftext">
```

or

```
<Texteinmischung Typ="Text" Position="Hinweistext">
```

How can I get the tags with the attributes?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you ask for something with `@Typ="Hinweistext"`, why would you expect it to find something with `@Position="Hinweistext"`?

Answer (score 2):

YSharp has given you answer to your particular problem, but you might interested to know there is another approach you can take, which takes advantage of XSLT's [built-in templates rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). If all you need is to output the various text nodes, just have a single template that matches text nodes in which you output the text with a line-break.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use the `xsl:strip-space` to ignore white-space only nodes.

If you wanted to ignore certain elements, like `Kursgebühr` just add an extra template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Kursgebühr" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

For the problematic copy-of, try instead:

```
<xsl:copy-of select=".//*[@Typ]" />
```

(because the context node at that point is a Kursstamm element, and to grab those Texteinmischung's with a "Typ" attribute, you need to go deeper on Kursstamm's descendant axis, not just get its direct children; hence the use of ".//*" in that case)

'HTH,

Comment: It works when in the structure always all tags are available.
In my XML is unfortunately not the case.
So I get when

Comment: Sorry - again:

It works when in the structure always all tags are available.
In my XML that is unfortunately not the case.
So I get when there is no (<Texteinmischung Typ="Text" Position="Hinweistext">Text F </Texteinmischung>
) "F" -- a "Text A" on that position!
I need to specify the attribute ether
Typ="Text" Position="Vorlauftext"
or
Typ="Text" Position="Hinweistext"

Thanks for your help!